# why can't compare string in #if expression in c++

Tags: c++

i want to write code like this but i can't:

```
#define COLOR "red" 
#define RED "red"
#define BLUE "blue"

int main()
{

// following code can't be compiled
#if (COLOR==RED)
    cout<<"red"<<endl;
#endif

// following code can work
if(COLOR==RED)
    cout<<"red"<<endl;
else 
    cout<<"notred"<<endl;

}
```

so how can i realize string compare in #if expression? or may be this is not possible?

BTW i know i can realize in other ways like following:

```
#define COLOR 1
#define RED 1
#define BLUE 2

// can be compiled and word correctly
#if(COLOR==RED)
    cout<<"red"<<endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to use the preprocessor for this?

Comment: Even `if (COLOR==RED)` is not required to be true. "Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object **[is unspecified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.string#9)**."

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel : 1  hope expressions have meaning as far as possilble, for me number 1 2 3 don't have any meaning.  in other word, i want a better reading experience. 2 in some cases, i want macro like COLOR entering my filename with content of "red" for example.

Comment: add a problem: how can i print the macro as a string into a filename?  as we know, macro will be replaced by proprocessor. Are there existing some tricky?

Comment: To extend what @RaymondChen said: `"red" == "red"` is not required to be true; the two literals can be stored separately, or they can be treated as a single literal.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but why use the preprocessor and not, huh, constants? You're writing C++, not C, you have real constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because #if only works with integers

> expression is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent restrictions. It may contain...

see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html#SEC38

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

// internal functions, can be put into included header
#define TRUE 1
#define XEQUAL(a, b) a##_##b
#define EQUAL(a, b) XEQUAL(a, b)
#define XCUSTOMSTR(a) color_##a
#define CUSTOMSTR(a) XCUSTOMSTR(a)
#define XSTR(a) #a
#define STR(a) XSTR(a)

// define available colors
#define red_red TRUE
#define blue_blue TRUE
#define green_green TRUE

// optional custom names
#define color_green "grün"

#define COLOR red
#define COLOR2 green

int main() {

#if EQUAL(COLOR, red)
    std::cout << "my_"STR(COLOR)"_file.txt";
#endif

#if EQUAL(COLOR, COLOR2)
    char filename[] = "my_"STR(COLOR2)"_file.txt";
    std::cout << filename;
#endif

    std::cout << CUSTOMSTR(green);

    return 0;
}
```

The trick is to compare *before* making a string out of it.

The preprocessor can not process strings (except generate them), but it can process textual tokens!

Comment: can't work , error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression

Comment: @Aerterliusi Comparison works now and you can use the macro text in filenames.